# Power BI changing text case automatically

Tags: powerbi

I have a power BI connected to a SQL Server, I am reading a text field that is case sensitive in my sql server, but when the data arrive in power BI is all in the same case.

For example in my database I have "mixed", "Mixed", "MIXED", when I read data from power BI all data is "mixed".

Does anyone know what is going on?

Many thx

Answer (score 1):

Power BI doesn't handle case sensitivity that well at the moment (after the query stage anyway).

You can vote for a related idea to fix this [here](https://ideas.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi-ideas/suggestions/17235656-case-sensitive-insensitive-option).

A current workaround is to [create a dimension table](http://www.thebiccountant.com/2015/08/17/create-a-dimension-table-with-power-query-avoid-the-bug/) with an index and work with that index instead.